# ¿ Cómo activar sistema de partículas en Unity?

Tags: unity

Estoy intentando activar un sistema de particulas en Unity el cual se encuentra desactivado en el medio de la pantalla.

Estoy probando usar Instantiate pero creo que no es la forma ya que lo tengo dentro de void update, no dentro de OnCollision... Paso la función donde quiero que vaya:

```
public class Colision : MonoBehaviour {


public ParticleSystem efectoParticulas;

.
.
.

 void Update () {

    if (Veces_Pequeño == 3) {
        Mover.velocidad = 0;
        Veces_Pequeño = 0;
        CanvasFinJuego = true;
        MiVariable = 1;
        EmpezarJuego.empezado = 0;
        // Aquí debería ir la instruccion , pero nada me funciona
        .
        .

  }
```

**Es decir, tengo un efecto de partículas en el medio de la pantalla siempre desactivado y cuando entre dentro del if anterior, se deberia activar, pero no lo logro**

He intentado con `emission.enabled = true` pero no se si lo pongo mal, pero me da error, alguna ayuda?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Mi código actual:

```
public class Colision : MonoBehaviour {


public ParticleSystem efectoParticulas;

.
.
.
 void start(){

 var emission = efectoParticulas.emission;
 emission.enabled = false;      

 }
 void Update () {

    if (Veces_Pequeño == 3) {
        var emission = efectoParticulas.emission;
        emission.enabled = true;
        .
        .

  }
 }
}
```

Y esta es la foto donde dentro de una esfera que he creado, tiene el script y le asigno el sistema de particulas dentro del public (ultima fila)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué error te da? Tal como lo describes, parece que tienes un elemento en el juego que está desactivado y quieres activarlo dentro del propio código, cosa que no te funcionaria porque está desactivado....

Comment: el caso es que no me hace absolutamente nada,no me cambia.

Comment: Es una pregunta tonta, pero ¿estás seguro que entra dentro del if? Lo digo porque en el código, no veo que tengas ninguna forma de que llegue a tres y la tienes publica con valor 0, por tanto no es estática y no entraría si no la actualizas. Puedes usar el código "Debug.Log("Hola")", donde "Hola" es cualquier palabra, para comprobar por consola si accede al if.

Comment: Si, si que accede, tengo tal debug ya puesto. Si no entra a ese if el juego no va, y me entra , comprobado al 100%.

Comment: Que puede estar pasando entonces? Esta bien declarado todo no?

Comment: Repasado, y si que entra al if que comentas, pero no funciona. Se hace con particlesystem tal como dijiste?

Comment: Es en 3D el proyecto, por si cambia algo...

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, colocando un efectoParticulas.Play(); dentro de una funcion que no devuelva nada.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder activar/desactivar el Sistema de partículas tienes varias opciones, pero como tu creas una referencia *"ParticleSystem"* al inicio (y no un GameObject), te voy a explicar como hacerlo en ese caso:

Lo primero, **NUNCA** desactives el objeto que contenga el sistema de partículas que quieres mostrar. Si no quieres que se vea al inicio del juego, desactívalo en la función *"Start()"* del script que maneja el sistema de partículas. Así no habrá problemas.

Ahora, como activar/desactivar, te pongo un ejemplo en donde manejas esto pulsado las flechas de dirección horizontales:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ActivarDesactivarParticulas : MonoBehaviour {

    public ParticleSystem efectoParticulas;

    // Desactivado al comiendo de la ejecución por defecto
    void Start() {
        var emission = efectoParticulas.emission;
        emission.enabled = false;
    }

    void Update () {

        // Es una referencia al componente emission del sistema de partículas
        var emission = efectoParticulas.emission;

        // Flecha derecha. Activará el sistema de partículas.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
            emission.enabled = true;
        }
        // Flecha izquierda. Desactivará el sistema de partículas.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
            emission.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Recuerda que tienes el sistema de partículas como *"public"* es decir que en el Inspector del editor de Unity tienes que añadirle al script el sistema de partículas que quieras manejar, si no, te devolverá un error *"NullReferenceException"*.

¡Mucha suerte!

Comment: vale perfecto gracias lo pruebo y te comento, por cierto,si no lo hiciera con particlesystem y lo hiciera con gameobject, sería muy distinto?

Comment: Si lo hicieras con un GameObject, en vez de usar "emission.enabled", usarías "go.SetActive(true/false)", siendo "go" el nombre de la variable referencia del GameObject. Esto no lo he probado personalmente, pero sí he visto otros juegos con esta práctica. Espero que te sirva. :)

Comment: Llevo muchas horas perdidas con esto y no puede ser tan complicado, veamos.... He hecho exactamente lo de arriba sin resultado y me sale este error : ``NullReferenceException: Do not create your own module instances, get them from a ParticleSystem instance UnityEngine.ParticleSystem+EmissionModule.set_enabled (Boolean value)`` y SÍ que he asignado al "public" mi efecto de particulas en unity, que lo tengo en un prefab. Un objeto que es el que se colisiona, tiene asignado dicho script y ahí me sale la casilla vacía que es donde introduzco el prefab de particulas. ¿ Por que me da fallo?

Comment: He añadido dos veces " var emission = efectoParticulas.emission;" porque si no, en update me decia que no existia ``emission``, a modo de dato, me sigue sin ir.

Comment: Actualiza el código de tu pregunta al que tienes actualmente y podré darte más ayuda. La verdad es que no es tan complicado (como dices), a ver si así te puedo ayudar más.

Comment: Hola, ya he actualizado la respuesta, arriba la tienes con lo que tengo y sigue sin funcionarme. Gracias.